# How do I specify number of items to be shown in Owl carousel 2?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, owl-carousel, owl-carousel-2

In Owl carousel 1 I could specify different number of items to be shown depending on the viewport width:

```
items:5,
itemsDesktop:[1199,4],
itemsDesktopSmall:[979,3],
itemsTablet:[768,2],
itemsMobile:[479,1]
```

However, the code above doesn't work with Owl carousel 2. Also the specs suggest the only option to use:

```
items: 3 // or any ther number here
```

So it's the same number of items shown on mobile and desktop. Did I miss something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using the `responsive` option. Read here in the docs:
https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/docs/api-options.html

On this thread hvsh is giving an example right at the bottom:
https://github.com/OwlCarousel2/OwlCarousel2/issues/1363

Also on the demo page they give an example:
https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/demos/responsive.html

Comment: Thanks, this helped.